# Extract confidence interval for both values of binary variable for glm()?

Tags: r, glm, confidence-interval

I want to analyze the relation between whether someone smoked or not and the number of drinks of alcohol.

The reproducible data set:

| smoking_status | alcohol_drinks |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 5 |

I have used glm() to analyse this relation:

```
glm <- glm(smoking_status ~ alcohol_drinks, data = data, family = binomial)
summary(glm)
confint(glm)
```

Using the above I'm able to extract the p-value and the confidence interval for the entire set.

However, I would like to extract the confidence interval for each smoking status, so that I can produce this results table:

|  | Alcohol drinks, mean (95%CI) | p-values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Smokers | X (X - X) | 0.492 |
| Non-smokers | X (X - X) |  |

How can I produce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the response `alcohol_drinks` is not binary, a logistic regression is out of the question. Since the response is counts data, I will fit a Poisson model.

To have confidence intervals for each binary value of `smoking_status`, coerce to factor and fit a model without an intercept.

```r
x <- 'smoking_status  alcohol_drinks
1   2
0   5
1   2
0   1
1   0
1   0
0   0
1   9
1   6
1   5'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)


pois_fit <- glm(alcohol_drinks ~ 0 + factor(smoking_status), data = df1, family = poisson(link = "log"))
summary(pois_fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = alcohol_drinks ~ 0 + factor(smoking_status), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
#>     data = df1)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -2.6186  -1.7093  -0.8104   1.1389   2.4957  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> factor(smoking_status)0   0.6931     0.4082   1.698   0.0895 .  
#> factor(smoking_status)1   1.2321     0.2041   6.036 1.58e-09 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 58.785  on 10  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 31.324  on  8  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 57.224
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
confint(pois_fit)
#> Waiting for profiling to be done...
#>                              2.5 %   97.5 %
#> factor(smoking_status)0 -0.2295933 1.399304
#> factor(smoking_status)1  0.8034829 1.607200
#>
exp(confint(pois_fit))
#> Waiting for profiling to be done...
#>                             2.5 %   97.5 %
#> factor(smoking_status)0 0.7948568 4.052378
#> factor(smoking_status)1 2.2333058 4.988822
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit

The edit to the question states that the problem was reversed, what is asked is to find out the effect of alcohol drinking on smoking status. And with a binary response, individuals can be smokers or not, a logistic regression is a possible model.

```r
bin_fit <- glm(smoking_status ~ alcohol_drinks, data = df1, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
summary(bin_fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = smoking_status ~ alcohol_drinks, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
#>     data = df1)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -1.7491  -0.8722   0.6705   0.8896   1.0339  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept)      0.3474     0.9513   0.365    0.715
#> alcohol_drinks   0.1877     0.2730   0.687    0.492
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 12.217  on 9  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 11.682  on 8  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 15.682
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

# Odds ratios
exp(coef(bin_fit))
#>    (Intercept) alcohol_drinks 
#>       1.415412       1.206413
exp(confint(bin_fit))
#> Waiting for profiling to be done...
#>                    2.5 %    97.5 %
#> (Intercept)    0.2146432 11.167555
#> alcohol_drinks 0.7464740  2.417211
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Another way to conduct a logistic regression is to regress the cumulative counts of smokers on increasing numbers of alcoholic drinks. In order to do this, the data must be sorted by `alcohol_drinks`, so I will create a second data set, `df2`. Code inspired this in [this RPubs post](https://rpubs.com/ajaydecis/logisticmodels).

```r
df2 <- df1[order(df1$alcohol_drinks), ]
Total <- sum(df2$smoking_status)
df2$smoking_status <- cumsum(df2$smoking_status)

fit <- glm(cbind(smoking_status, Total - smoking_status) ~ alcohol_drinks, data = df2, family = binomial())
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = cbind(smoking_status, Total - smoking_status) ~ 
#>     alcohol_drinks, family = binomial(), data = df2)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -0.9714  -0.2152   0.1369   0.2942   0.8975  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)     -1.1671     0.3988  -2.927 0.003428 ** 
#> alcohol_drinks   0.4437     0.1168   3.798 0.000146 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 23.3150  on 9  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance:  3.0294  on 8  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 27.226
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
# Odds ratios
exp(coef(fit))
#>    (Intercept) alcohol_drinks 
#>      0.3112572      1.5584905
exp(confint(fit))
#> Waiting for profiling to be done...
#>                    2.5 %    97.5 %
#> (Intercept)    0.1355188 0.6569898
#> alcohol_drinks 1.2629254 2.0053079

plot(smoking_status/Total ~ alcohol_drinks, 
     data = df2,
     xlab = "Alcoholic Drinks",
     ylab = "Proportion of Smokers")
lines(df2$alcohol_drinks, fit$fitted, type="l", col="red")
title(main = "Alcohol and Smoking")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Since smoking is a dummy variable, surely the confidence interval for the intercept is the same as the confidence interval for non-smokers? Do you really need to convert to factors and fit without an intercept? Also, the confidence intervals will be log scale here, so you need to exponentiate them to get the 95% confidence intervals in terms of alcoholic drinks. The p values relate to the probability that the actual coefficient is different from 0, i.e. its exponent is significantly different from 1, so I'm not sure the OP knows what the p values mean here.

Comment: @BenBolker Yes! Sorry, weekend...

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the dependent variable should be smoking or not smoking (binary), and the independent variable should be alcohol consumtion. So glm(smoking_status ~ alcohol_drinks) and so forth. I will edit my above post. Do you have any advice as for my question with this in mind? Kind regards

Comment: @RuiBarradas: **thank you!** However, I was looking to extract the mean (95% CI). If I understand you correctly, the above bin_fit example gives me the OR (95% CI), right?

Comment: @Bedui Yes, remove `exp` to have results in the log scale, but that's not what you are after. Logistic regression assumes that `p/(1-p)` follows a logistic distribution and the odds ratio is the normal way of presenting results, that's the values you want. In logistic regression the relation between the regressors and the response is not linear, what is linear is the relation between the regressors and the log odds. As a result, parameters' estimates are frequently reported as odds ratios and this includes the 95% CI's.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: Ah yes, true. Thank you for the good explanation also. I realized I need to be able to find a solution simiilar to my original question also, but with negative values as well for which poisson doesn't work. But since it's a different question I made it a new post, so not to confuse too much: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72510602/extract-confidence-interval-for-both-values-of-binary-variable-when-dependent-v. :-) If you would like to help in it as well. Thank you for your help with this one.