# Method to extract mean (CI 95%) when independent variable is continuous (both pos and neg) and dependent variable is binary?

Tags: r, mean, confidence-interval

(This question is similar to [Extract confidence interval for both values of binary variable for glm()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72499784/extract-confidence-interval-for-both-values-of-binary-variable-for-glm), however in this example the continuous variable includes negative values, and the dependent and independent variables have swapped places)

The reproducible data set:

| smoking_status (0 = non-smokers, 1 = smokers) | change_hemoglobin | age | sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 | 12 | 0 |
| 0 | -5.2 | 99 | 0 |
| 1 | -2.0 | 54 | 1 |
| 0 | 1.7 | 46 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 45 | 1 |
| 1 | 0.1 | 24 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 24 | 1 |
| 1 | 9.05 | 78 | 0 |
| 1 | 6.0 | 56 | 0 |
| 1 | -5.2 | 45 | 0 |

With which method can I extract the mean and confidence intervals for the change in hemoglobin for each smoking status? I would like to produce a results table like this, including the p-value for the difference in change of hemoglobin between the smokers and non-smokers:

**Unadjusted:**

|  | Change in hemoglobin, mean (95% CI) | p-value of difference between smokers and non-smokers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Smokers | X (X - X) | X |
| Non-smokers | X (X - X) |  |

**Adjusted for age and sex:**

|  | Change in hemoglobin, mean (95% CI) | p-value of difference between smokers and non-smokers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Smokers | X (X - X) | X |
| Non-smokers | X (X - X) |  |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract confidence interval for both values of binary variable for glm()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72499784/extract-confidence-interval-for-both-values-of-binary-variable-for-glm)

Comment: Please explain why the answer to your previous version of this question - which you have accepted - does not provide the information you need.

Comment: Hi @Limey. Because this data set includes negative values, for which the answer with poisson (which was suggested to extract mean and CI) does not work. Also, dependent vs independent variable have swapped in this question (pardon me being novice in statistics if Im wrong now…). Since the data sets are different I thought an additional question in the comments of the previous question would be confusing. But do you prefer that I ask the question there instead?

Comment: OK, that's fair enough.  Though I would hope that the answers to your previous question should have given you enough to at least *attempt* a solution of your own.  As an aside, a model in which your predictor is binary is unlikely ever to provide a good prediction for a dependent that is continuous.

Comment: Thank you @Limey. I've tried myself for at least a few hours now, so I can assure you I do so. Sometimes I get stuck in an issue and it's hard to get passed it. That's when I ask for help here, to just give me that hint and then I can hopefully get the rest myself.

Comment: Using coef(glm(change_hemoglobin ~ 0 + as.factor(smoking_status), data = abc, family = gaussian)), I can extract the correct mean values. But using confint() with the same glm(), the confidence intervals are incorrect. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Limey I'm not sure about a binary predictor being unlikely to ever give a good prediction of a continuous variable. If you have two distinct populations, each with its own mean and small standard deviations, then the binary measure of population will be highly predictive, no?

Comment: @AllanCameron. If the conditions you state hold true AND if the binary predictor is a good predictor of population membership, then yes - I agree with you.  However, I did say *unlikely* (rather than *impossible*) because, based on experience, I feel your conditions are unlikely to hold.

Comment: @Limey you're probably right. There are a few counter examples, though not very common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a few base R functions. The mean for each group can simply be obtained by `mean`. The 95% confidence interval around the mean can be obtained by calculating the mean +/- 1.96 standard errors, and the p value can be obtained from a single-sample t test:

```r
with(df, tapply(change_hemoglobin, smoking_status, function(x) {
  mean_x <- round(mean(x), 2)
  sem_x <- round(sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)), 2)
  paste0(mean_x, ' (95% CI ', 
         mean_x - 1.96 * sem_x, ' to ', mean_x + 1.96 * sem_x, '),',
         ' p = ', round(t.test(x)$p.val, 2))
  }))

#>                                            0 
#> "-1.17 (95% CI -5.2468 to 2.9068), p = 0.63" 
#>                                            1 
#> "1.49 (95% CI -2.0772 to 5.0572), p = 0.44"
```

---

**Update**

To take sex and age into account, we need a linear model:

```r
df$smoking_status <- factor(df$smoking_status)

model1 <- lm(change_hemoglobin ~ 0 + smoking_status + age + sex, data = df)

model2 <- lm(change_hemoglobin ~ smoking_status + age + sex, data = df)

coefs <- summary(model1)$coef
coefs2 <- summary(model2)$coef

c(paste0('Mean change: ', round(coefs[1:2, 1], 2), ', 95% CI: ',
      round(coefs[1:2, 1] - 1.96 * coefs[1:2, 2], 2), ' to ',
      round(coefs[1:2, 1] + 1.96 * coefs[1:2, 2], 2)),
  paste("p value = ", 
        round(coefs2[2, 4], 2)))
#> [1] "Mean change: -0.05, 95% CI: -13.14 to 13.04"
#> [2] "Mean change: 2.27, 95% CI: -7.29 to 11.82"  
#> [3] "p value =  0.58"
```

Comment: That's perfect. And for non-normally distributed variables I guess I can just change t.test for wilcox.test?

Comment: @Bedui it depends how large your sample set is and how far it deviates from normality. If you have a large enough sample, a t test should still be fine.

Comment: Thank you Allan. If I would like to adjust for a third variable, say Age, in the above code, and get both the mean, CI and p-values adjusted, how would I do that?

Comment: And one more question @allan-cameron: your example gives two different p-values. I'm looking for one p-value that examines if the mean (CI) are different for the two groups.

Comment: You can simply do a t.test between the two samples `t.test(change_in_hemoglobin ~ smoking_status, data = df)`

Comment: Thank you. But how about the adjusted mean and confidence intervals? I.e. for example the mean and confidence interval of change_in_hemoglobin for each smoking status, after adjustment for age and sex? (I've now added two extra columns to my sample data to illustrate this)

Comment: That's a completely different question Bedui. Your edits have now made my answer look incomplete at best... I will have a look when I get back to my PC, but essentially you will need to run a linear model here, and use the coefficients from that.

Comment: Thank you Allan. I'm sorry that my initial question was not clear enough.

Comment: @Bedui your initial question was clear enough; it's just that you changed it into a different question that requires a different answer! Anyway, see my update.

Comment: Thank you Allan. So do I interpret the results correctly also when I conclude that, adjusted for age and sex, the change in haemoglobin was for smokers [smoking_status = 1] 2.27 (CI 2.18 to 6.71), and it was not significantly different (p = 0.71) from that of non-smokers? **---**
_Intuitively I would have thought this difference was significant though, given how far away the upper confidence interval of non-smokers (-0.15) is from the lower confidence interval of smokers (2.18). But maybe the low number of participants is not enough to render significance, right?_

Comment: Sorry, you're right Bedui, I made the wrong calculation. The updated version is now correct. The estimates and 95% confidence intervals are for non-smokers and smokers (adjusted for sex and age), and the p value is for the difference between the two groups, again adjusted for age and sex.

Comment: Hi again @allan-cameron. When I run this on my actual dataset (a dozen variables to adjust for, and tens of thousands of participants), I get very different results before and after adjustment which suprises me. I've tried to see if the results for the example above are reasonable, and one thing that puzzles me is that for "coefs2", the intercept is the same as smoking_status0 in "coefs", and that smoking_status1 is different in "coefs" and "coefs2". Could this really be correct? I cant see the logic behind that. Do you find it logical? Could there be another error in this formula?

Comment: Basically I get in my results of coefs: smoking_status0: 19.62; **smoking_status1:  19.77**. But in my results of coefs2: (Intercept): 19.62; **smoking_status1: 0.15**. The rest of the variables show the same estimates.

Comment: This is correct @Bedui - when you have an intercept, the value for smoking = 1 is _in addition_ to the intercept. Note that 19.62 + 0.15 = 19.77